# django exedittabledataview search columns

Tags: django, x-editable

I am trying to make a search option for my data table in my site,

in models.py I have:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, db_index = True)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField( db_index = True )
    event_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    capture_rule = models.ForeignKey(CaptureRule, db_index = True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(EventStatus, null = True, blank=True, db_index = True)
    comment = models.TextField( null = True, blank = True )
    source_url = models.CharField(max_length=4096, null = True, blank = True )
    links = models.ManyToManyField( Link, related_name = 'events' )
```

and in my views.py:

```
class edittest(XEditableDatatableView):
model = Event
template_name = 'webapp/index.html'

datatable_options = {
    'columns':[( 'Time', 'creation_time', 'get_event_age' ),
                ( 'Status', 'status', make_xeditable( type='select' ), 'status__name' ),
                ( 'Creator', 'creator' ),
                ( 'Source', 'source' ),
                ( 'Title', 'title' ),
                ( 'Body', 'body', 'get_body_with_markup' ),
                'comment',
                'id',
                'source_url',
                ( 'Tag', 'capture_rule__tag__name' ),
                ( 'Matcher', 'capture_rule__matcher'),
                'linked_urls',
                'capture_rule'

    ],
    'search_fields': [ 'status__name' ],
    'hidden_columns' : ['body', 'comment', 'id', 'source_url', 'linked_urls', 'capture_rule' ],
    'ordering':['-creation_time'],
}
```

and it works ok but when I change the search_fields parameter to

```
'search_fields': [ 'title' ] or  'search_fields': [ 'comment' ]
```

it search in the whole columns like if I wrote : `'search_fields': []`

Comment: side note, django already adds an id primary key, so why you add a `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` ? Also, is MyModel equal to Event in your question?

Comment: you right but meanwhile i am focusing on search option

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the search field should not already appear in the column list.

> A list of filter-like ORM fields that are always appended to the list
>   of search fields when a search is performed on the table. 
>   `search_fields` should only contain ORM paths to fields that aren't
>   already in the column definitions, since those are already searched by
>   default.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datatable-view/0.5.5

Comment: any idea why when i search some expression that is in the source column it not found??

Comment: @OmegaDoe can you do an example of the actual query and the data you have in the db, maybe modifying your question if that's strictly relevant to the original question.